# Gaskets for tap/faucet for drinking water

Tags: water, taps

Because a tap in our kitchen (used for drinking water) is dripping and the gasket* is old, I want to replace it. I find numerous gaskets on the market that would fit, but it always says on the packing "for household, but not for drinking water", or nothing at all. Not only in the internet, but even asking in several specialized stores, the reaction after asking for "drinking water approved gaskets" is astonishment.

*) Since there seem different translations and this was asked in the comments: by "gasket" I mean the "seal", the (usually black, sometimes reddish) rubber-like ring that prevents leaking, see image. Please correct my wording for this if necessary (just looked it up in the dictionary).

[image]

Questions:

1. Is there (as I believed) something like drinking-water approved gaskets (Germany: "KTW-Zulassung für Trinkwasser", "DVGW", "DIN")? Otherwise at least drinking-water appropriate, and how would I recognize that? (sth. like the Canadian http://www.canadarubbergroup.com/safe-materials-for-drinking-water-gaskets/)
2. Probably I am not allowed to ask for companies/distribution partners, but maybe someone has a hint on an appropriate search terms (German market). So far, my searches find products that are NOT driking water compatible (but contain all search terms plus a "not").

Comment: By "gasket" do you mean the packing around the stem of a faucet? Or do you mean the plastic "washer" in older faucets which seals against a brass seat?

Comment: @jimstewart OP has one of those strap-on kits that pierces a pipe.

Comment: edited question and added image to make things clear

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

This puzzled me. After some looking, I think this is referring to the NSF 61 standards, or a similar European/German standard. If that's the case, the phrase "for household, but not for drinking water" would mean that the product has not been approved for use in an industrial system that processes drinking water, but should be acceptable for household use.

In that case, I'd recommend just looking up the possible materials, and buying a gasket that uses a material you like the look of.

Comment: Thanks, but actually I am looking specifically for sth. I can use for equipment and standards for /drinking water/, on the /German/European market/.

Answer (score 0):

Faucets with those types of sealing washer are outmoded for kitchen faucets and bathrooms but many are still in use in the US.

They are still sold use in the US for outdoor faucets. It sounds to me like Germany is engaging in overzealous regulation. I cannot imagine any basis for considering this would to a health hazard, but if that is the way it is and you want to comply then you will have to change the faucet to a new model.

You may be able to stop the leak by flipping the washer seal. But somethimes the "valve seat" gets grooved by erosion from leaking water over time. Then the seat must be removed and either refaced or replaced with a new one.

How long has this been leaking? Sometimes people use Teflon tape on the threads of the valve seat and a piece lays across the seat causing a leak. A valve seat does not require any sealant on its threads because it is the flat shoulder that seals. The threading is to supply the compression force to the flat metal sealing surfaces.